# Alternative way to find the decimal at a specific position

Tags: python

I've written a solution to find the one number of digits after decimal.

```
print(round(((10**(eval(input('Digits after decimal:  '))))*(eval(input('Enter Number:  ')))//1)%10))
```

This program is working correctly, but I need another way. Because I have to solve this program in two way.

example :

Digits after decimal: 5

Enter Number: 1257.515491

Output : 9

Do you have any other way of using math or programming functions?

Comment: '1257.515491'.split('.')[-1][5-1]

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? `eva(input(...))` is one of the worst things you can do in any language as you are providing the user a way to execute its own code.

Comment: Start by not putting everything on a single line, so you can actually make some sense of your code. https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/5cdda442be3979babe44a18e507752a3 is the same logic, but using `int()` instead of `// 1`, and `int()` and `float()` instead of `eval()`. The `round()` call is entirely redundant, and it really doesn't need as many parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if better, but definitely a cleaner solution:

- Convert to a string
- Split by "."
- Take the nth character of the part after the "."

```py
>>> num = 1257.515491
>>> str(num).split('.')[1][4]
'9'
```

Of course, you can convert it back to a number afterward.

Comment: Since they use `input()`, just dropping the `eval()` call would already leave it a string..

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
digit=int(input('Digits after decimal:  '))
number=float(input('Enter Number:  '))

print(str(number).split('.')[-1][digit-1])
```

input :

```
Digits after decimal:  5
Enter Number:  1257.515491
```

output

```
9
```

Comment: @splash58 suggested the same in a comment with the exception of using `[-1]` instead of `[1]`. They both work for properly formated float numbers and none of them work for integers.

Comment: @splash58 It's true, edited

Comment: Drop the `float()` call; there is no need to convert a string to float and then the float back to a string here.

Comment: With float() and a false Input like "aaaaa" you will get ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'aaaaaaa'. But without it's IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly turn the number into a string, split by "." and then look for the [n-1] element in that sub-list.